# apache rewrite > nginx rewrite

Tags: nginx, .htaccess, rewrite, codeigniter

I finnaly got nginx running

my site are made with codeigniter 
and I have this old rewrite from my .htaccess

```
#map all request urls to a specific controller method
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/welcome/domain/$1 [L]
```

my question is how do I convert it to a working nginx rewrite rule?

Answer (score 2):

Try to use [apache-to-nginx converter](http://www.anilcetin.com/convert-apache-htaccess-to-nginx/). It works in most cases.
With your example it returns:

```
rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?/welcome/domain/$1 last;
```