# NGINX Rewrite Rule for Slug

Tags: linux, nginx, web-server, rewrite, web-hosting

I am trying to create a rewrite rule in NGINX for a URL.

The Original URL format is `https://example.com/blog/article-slug-here`

but needs to be in this format:

```
https://example.com/blog?article=article-slug-here
```

any suggestions?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [apache rewrite > nginx rewrite](https://serverfault.com/questions/339691/apache-rewrite-nginx-rewrite)

Comment: Figured out using the following link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59846238/guide-on-how-to-use-regex-in-nginx-location-block-section

Comment: please add an answer in case it has been solved or i have to review this question a thousand times again ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to figure it out using the documentation provided on another post located here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59846238/guide-on-how-to-use-regex-in-nginx-location-block-section